# Summary row with LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have table like this:

```
title row1 row2
'p1'  3    4
'p2'  23   43
'p3'  21   23
```

and I want to have additional summary row in this table:

```
title   row1  row2
'p1'    3     4
'p2'    23    43
'p3'    21    23
'total' 47    70
```

how to do that in simple way with LINQ? I have many columns so query like that:

```
Row r = new Row();
r.row1 = list.Sum(x=>x.row1);
r.row2 = list.Sum(x=>x.row2);
```

is not good idea (in my opinion)...

Answer (score 3):

You can combine it into a single LINQ query like this:

```
var result = row
.Select(r => r)
.Union(new Row[]
    {
       new Row
           {
               Title = "total",
               Row1 = row.Sum(r => r.Row1),
               Row2 = row.Sum(r => r.Row2)
           },
    });
```

But ultimately you are still individually summing the rows. I can't think of a way around that.

Answer (score 1):

I can't see an obvious way of improving on what you're suggesting

```
var total = new List<Row>{new Row{
        title="total", 
        row1=rows.Sum(r1=>r1.row1), 
        row2=rows.Sum(r2=>r2.row2)
    }};

var q = rows.Concat(total);
```